# substr Chinese string after first space in R

Tags: r, substr, cjk

How can I extract Chinese characters after a space?

The original data is below:

```
10:36   不願做奴隸的人們    然後看你有沒有在時間內申覆。
10:37   千里之外    真的很無奈
10:37   不願做奴隸的人們    如果五天內你沒注意信心，表示你默認。
```

The data that I need is:

```
不願做奴隸的人們
千里之外
不願做奴隸的人們
```

The code that I used is:

```
filedata <- scan(file = ,what = "",sep = "\n",encoding = "UTF-8")

#定义数据框和变量
data <- data.frame(user_name = c(),date = c(),date = c())
date <- vector(length=length(filedata)) 
time <- vector(length=length(filedata))
user_name <- vector(length=length(filedata))
text <- vector(length=length(filedata))

#截取用户名、时间和日期
pat1 = '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}'  #表示日期的正则表达式
pat2 = '[0-9]+:[0-9]+'               #表示时间的正则表达式
for(i in 1: length(filedata)){
  dt_pattern1 <- grepl(pat1,filedata[i]) #grepl函数识别每条记录中的日期部分
  dt_pattern2 <- grepl(pat2,filedata[i]) #grepl函数识别每条记录中的时间部分
  if(dt_pattern1 == TRUE){
    date[i] <- substr(filedata[i],1,10)
  } 
  if(dt_pattern2 == TRUE){
    time[i] <- substr(filedata[i],1,5)
    user_name[i] <- substr(filedata[i], 7, "\\s")
  }
}
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(Name = user_name,date = date,time = time))
```

I need to create a Name variable, but it has a warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

Can anyone help to debug？ Thank you very much！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is a vector of strings, you can split the strings by any white space, and extract the second element in each split string.

```
library(stringr)

user_name <- c(
  "10:36   不願做奴隸的人們    然後看你有沒有在時間內申覆。",
  "10:37   千里之外    真的很無奈",
  "10:37   不願做奴隸的人們    如果五天內你沒注意信心，表示你默認。"
)

str_split(user_name, "\\s+", simplify = T)[, 2]
[1] "不願做奴隸的人們" "千里之外"         "不願做奴隸的人們"
```

Comment: Understood, Thanks so much! Can I ask one more question?

Original data
`"21:40 速哥 我被封的原因是 我散播客人資訊 我既沒有轉貼什麼 或是討論什麼 完全沒有 就無故亂封"`

What if the string that  I need is 
`"我被封的原因是 我散播客人資訊 我既沒有轉貼什麼 或是討論什麼 完全沒有 就無故亂封" `
which the string after second spaces, the code that I used cant work.             
`str_split(user_name, "\\s+", simplify = T)[, 3]`

Comment: @梁聖宇 In this case the logic would be different. It's better to standardise your input, otherwise, you'll need extra codes to deal with these special cases. In this case you can try replacing `[, 3]` with `[, 3:8]` and maybe wrap it with a `paste0()` to concatenate them together

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the first word from the username, you could use `sub()` here:

```r
user_name <- "不願做奴隸的人們    如果五天內你沒注意信心，表示你默認。"
first <- sub("(\\S+).*", "\\1", user_name)
first
```